# How can I execute a function on pressing the enter key in an <input> field?

Tags: javascript, events, input, listener

I have an input and I'd simply like to add an event listener for it to activate a function when I press enter, when the input is focused. How do I do this with pure JS?

Right now I have:

HTML:

```html
Enter your wage:<input type="text" id="wage" value ="" size=20>
<button id="sub">Submit</button>
```

JavaScript:

```js
var wage = document.getElementById("wage");
wage.addEventListener("change", validate);

var btn = document.getElementById("sub");
btn.addEventListener("click", validate);
```

So basically the function `validate()` activates when I click OR change the text, but I want to call it by pressing enter.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var wage = document.getElementById("wage");
wage.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.code === "Enter") {  //checks whether the pressed key is "Enter"
        validate(e);
    }
});

function validate(e) {
    var text = e.target.value;
    //validation of the input...
}
```

**[Live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/TazQ5/1/)**

Comment: +1. Though you could replace the `alert()` with `validate()`.

Comment: All browsers which supports `addEventListener` (IE9+, check out here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Comment: Use named functions instead of anonymous, because it would be impossible to remove this listener.

Comment: One important detail *e.keyCode* is currently deprecated, the new correct way is *e.key*  
  
**References**
  
//e.keyCode  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode  
   
//e.key  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Comment: Why is the ```e``` used? and Can we execute the code without it?

Comment: @iatharva How will you know what key was pressed if you do not make use of the `event` parameter?

Comment: Should be `.key` not `.code`. If `.code` is used and Enter is pressed on a 10key it will come through as 'NumpadEnter', not 'Enter', but when you use .key it always comes through as 'Enter'.

Comment: If you do string comparison using the key property then you should probably also compare with keyboard constants. So you would check `(event.key==Keyboard.ENTER)`. This prevents typos and case sensitive errors. However, I can't find the class right now

Answer (score 7):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("wage");
elem.onkeyup = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
       validate();
    }
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/aMgLK/

Answer (score 7):

Here is a version of the currently accepted answer (from @MinkoGechev) with [key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values) instead of keyCode:

```
const wage = document.getElementById('wage');
wage.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        validate(e);
    }
});

function validate(e) {
    const text = e.target.value;
    //validation of the input...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = document.getElementById("todo-item");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("sub").click(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: In this code when the user enter the input text and click on enter so it will automatically generated the result.

Comment: So, incorporate the explanation in the answer by editing it. Explained code is more likely to be useful to other people. ;)

Comment: This is the first time i have uploaded the code so i am sorry!

Answer (score 1):

HTML:
Enter your wage:

```
<input type="text" id="wage" value ="" onkeypress="myFunction(event)" size=20>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction(event) {
    var x = event.code;
    if(x == "Enter") {
        validate();
    }    
}
```

[w3schools - KeyboardEvent code Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_code.asp)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple. You can do this using keyup event.

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "#wage", function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    alert("Hi")
  }
})
```

Comment: This question doesn't mention jQuery. Please before answering, check if it mentions the Library/Programming Language in the tags or the body

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like
`wage.addEventListener('keydown', validate);`

Your validate function would then need to check `event.keyCode == 13` to determine 'enter' keypress.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your button element to a

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

it will work with the enter button on your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Or with jQuery

```
$("#wage").on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {  //checks whether the pressed key is "Enter"
        validate(e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `key` attribute of the KeyboardEvent, documentation on that can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key). You can also make the code much shorter by using a lambda function and an AND (&&) operator.

Here's how I would do it:

```js
document.querySelector('#wage').addEventListener('keypress', e => e.key === 'Enter' && validate(e));
```

The AND operator first checks whether `e.key` is equal to 'Enter', and if that is true it executes the `validate` function. If `e.key` is not 'Enter' it will not reach the `validate` function and will not execute it.

Comment: If you do string comparison using the key property then you should probably also compare with keyboard constants. So you would check (event.key==Keyboard.ENTER). This prevents typos and case sensitive errors. However, I can't find the class right now

Answer (score 0):

> I know there are very nice and different solutions. But I want to add one more thing. Because I didn't see it among the answers.In this situation "onkeydown" can be used.I see a lot of solution with keyup method.

- It is a DOM Level 2 (2001) feature.
- It is fully supported in all browsers.
- The onkeydown() method runs when a keyboard key is pressed. The onkeyup() method works when a finger is lifted from a keyboard key.

  ```
     document.querySelector("#wage").onkeydown = (e) => {
         if(e.keyCode === 13){  //enter
     document.querySelector(".add").click();
      }
        if(e.keyCode === 46){ // delete
     document.querySelector(".delete").click();
     }};
  ```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
    var key = e.which;

    if (key == 13) // the enter key ascii code
    {
        login();
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I'm downvoting this for 2 reasons: 1) there is no explanation. 2) this event will trigger on every keypress on every object and the login will execute anytime Enter is pressed anywhere, but the event should only be triggered on 1 or more specific elements.