# How to pass "this" on an enter key event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think this is a syntax question, but I can't seem to find a question that answers what I'm looking for. There's lots that are... close. Might be something with binding, or "apply", but I can't figure out how to use those in this context.

I have a function, that when fired, turns a span into an input so it can be edited. Then, when the focus is off (blur), the new text is saved. So far that works exactly as I wanted. I thought it would be nice if enter key would do the same thing... but I can't figure out how to make the event work.

```
function span_into_textarea() {
    var old_text = $(this).text();
    var editableText = $("<input type='text' />");
    editableText.val(old_text);
    $(this).replaceWith(editableText);
    editableText.focus();
    editableText.blur(textarea_into_span);
    editableText.keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {textarea_into_span()}
    }); // THIS DOESNT PASS ANYTHING TO "THIS"
    editableText.keypress(textarea_into_span); //THIS WORKS BUT I CAN'T KNOW WHICH KEY WAS PRESSED
}

function textarea_into_span() {
    var new_text = $(this).val();
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [execute function on enter key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011312/execute-function-on-enter-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to pass the `this` reference:

```
editableText.keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {textarea_into_span.call(this)} //will refer to editableText
});
```

Comment: You have three of those functions: `bind`, `call` and `apply`. It's worthwhile to look into them.

Answer (score 2):

1. You may [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind): `editableText.keypress( textarea_into_span.bind(this) )` (event is passed as an argument).
2. You may replace `textarea_into_span` with an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (they don't bind `this` so it is looked up in parent context):

   ```
   editableText.keypress( (e) => {
     if (e.which == 13) {
       var new_text = $(this).val();
     }
   })
   ```
3. As suggested by @Mouser you may use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

   ```
   editableText.keypress( function(e) {
     if (e.which == 13) {
       textarea_into_span.call(this);
       // or textarea_into_span.apply(this)
     }
   })
   ```

Comment: Arrow will only work on modern browser, should be nice as a disclaimer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, you were losing the scope:

```
function span_into_textarea() {
    var modify = this;
    var old_text = $(this).text();
    var editableText = $("<input type='text' />");
    editableText.val(old_text);
    $(this).replaceWith(editableText);
    editableText.focus();
    editableText.blur(textarea_into_span(modify));
    editableText.keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {textarea_into_span(modify)}
    });
}

function textarea_into_span(modify) {
    var new_text = $(modify).val();
}
```

Comment: As long as you're in the scope of the function this will work!

Answer (score 0):

```
editableText.keypress(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13) // enter key ascii code
    {
        textarea_into_span.call(this) //will refer to editableText
    }
});
```

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer