# How to add enter?

Tags: javascript, html

Hey so right now i have the code below that functions as a Ctrl+F search but within a search box. The website im using this on only have one code area so i need the code to function within the same one.

The code below does what i want it to do but at this moment we need to click on the search button the first time and then we can follow up with enter after that. What i want it to do is make it possible to accept the enter key from the start and at the same time have the button as an option.

Is this possible?

```
<!--BEGIN SEARCH BOX -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div class="search_box">
<div><input id="search" type="textarea" /> <input id="submit_form" onclick="checkInput()" type="button" value="Sök" /></div>

<div>&nbsp;</div>

<div>
<p>2019-11-11 - 2020-01-10 - Testing line 837<br />
<a href="">PDF</a></p>

<p>2019-11-04 - 2019-11-24 - Testing 2, line 607, 627, 697<br />
<a href="">PDF</a></p>

<p>2019-10-30 - 2019-11-29 - Testing 3, line 55, 75, 291<br />
<a href="">PDF</a></p>

<p>2019-10-31 - 2019-11-04 - Testing 4, line 423,424<br />
<a href="">PDF</a></p>
</div>
</div>
<!--END SEARCH BOX --><script>
    function checkInput() {
        var query = document.getElementById('search').value;
        window.find(query);
        return true;
    }                           
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have indicated that you cannot use a `form` tag due to restrictions on your hosting system. I dare say that your company may need to look into that, but a workaround solution may be to catch the `Enter` keypress on your input, as described here: [execute function on enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011312/execute-function-on-enter-key)

In your case this might look like this:

```html
var searchbox = document.getElementById("search");
searchbox.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {  //checks whether the pressed key is "Enter"
        checkInput();
    }
});
```

Comment: You are the angel! I have been going nuts about this. It works now. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Your input type is a `textarea`, so hitting Enter will be interpreted as creating a new line within that box. Change it to:

`<input id="search" type="text" />`

for a single line text field, and `Enter` will submit the form.
Which, by the way, you should probably enclose your inputs in, and change button type to submit:

```html
<form onsubmit="checkInput()">
<input id="search" type="text" /> <input id="submit_form" type="submit" value="Sök" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Thomas!

This works better but now it reloads my page as soon as i click enter tho

Comment: return false from your javascript function to stop submission of the form.

Comment: its not making a difference for me, although the site im putting this on works as database for our company in which we search for guides. This means my code area is limited and i now notice that when i use the <form> tag and ones i save and enter the code area again that tag is removed.

I guess it does not like that tag :/

Answer (score 0):

If i only use the following it works even if i have return set to true or false. It works almost perfectly, if i type anything in the box i need to click the button the first time and can then continue by clicking enter on my keyboard and it continues the search going down. I just have to click the button the first time and thats what annoys me :/

```
<div><input id="search" type="text" /> <input id="submit_form" onclick="checkInput()" type="button" value="Sök" /></div>
```

the "onclick" is what i want as onsubmit i guess but i cant just change that to onsubmit couse that will brake it.