# Search by pressing the enter key on keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, button

Trying to also search by pressing enter key. Works with the button but for some reason the code i have for the key press is not working. 
Javascript:

```
function displayMatches() {
         const searchText = document.querySelector('.search').value;
        const matchArray = findMatches(searchText, name);  
        const html = matchArray.map(place => {
            const regex = new RegExp(searchText);
            const nameName = place.name.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${searchText}</span>`);
            return `
            <a href="${place.url}" target="_blank">
                <li>
                    <span class="name">${nameName} <br> ${(place.price)}</span> 
                    <img src="${place.imgurl}" alt="Drink Image" height="87.5" width="100">
                </li>
            </a>
            `;
        }).join('');
        suggestions.innerHTML = html;
    }



const suggestions = document.querySelector('.suggestions');

const searchBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-search');
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', displayMatches);

var input = document.getElementById('.search');
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById('.btn-search').click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Is your keyup event listener firing?

Comment: Why are you not calling the the `displayMatches` function inside the keyup event handler instead of programmatically clicking the button? You might want to include your HTML so we can see what your `.search` element is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [execute function on enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011312/execute-function-on-enter-key)  It uses keydown instead of keyup.

Comment: You're searching for elements with `id=".search"` and `id=".btn-search"`.  Is this what you intend? This looks like you're thinking you're searching for a class name.

Comment: Do you have some html with that

Comment: yes they are classes

Comment: <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Search Deals">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this and I think it can helped you

JavaScript:

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  var x = event.keyCode;
  if (x == 27) {
    // 27 is the ESC key
    alert ("You pressed the Escape key!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
document.getElementById('.btn-search').click();
```

Are you sure `.btn-search` is a id property? Seems like a class property. You cannot get the element with `getElementById` if the "btn-search" isn't the id of the element.

And you don't need to set "." (class) or "#" (id) on the `getElementById` (`getElementById` it's only to get elements by id, so you don't need to tell the script the property type you searching).

Answer (score 1):

As the user `William Carneiro` stated, the issue is the `.` character.

The function `getElementById` just receive the id, not a selector. [Check documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Change this line:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('.search');
```

With something like this:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('search');
```

... or this:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('#search');
```

Also, make sure that your element has `id="search"`, it seems that probably you want to find an element with the class search instead.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('.search');
```

Comment: Which one you tried?... also confirm that there's no other elements with the same id. Anyway, are you sure that you're no looking for a class instead of an id? and if theres only one element with that class/id.

You can put a breakpoint on that line and confirm that the element retrieved (if any) is the one that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok most of your code was working

A few things to note

- When using **query selector** and calling a class use the class name with the dot`'.search-btn'`
- When using **getElementById** remember there is no Dot `'search-btn'`
- Also I think I added an id in few places make sure your html tags have Id attributes to them before using *getElementById* i.e `class='search-btn' id='search-btn' ...>`

Other than that your code works

```js
function displayMatches() {
         const searchText = document.querySelector('.search').value;
         // the rest of your code here
          console.log("enter Worked Searching" );
    }



const suggestions = document.querySelector('.suggestions');

const searchBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-search');
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', displayMatches);

var input = document.getElementById('search');
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById('btn-search').click();
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="search" id = 'search'type="text" placeholder="Search Deals">
<input type='button' class='btn-search' value='search' id ='btn-search'>
```

Comment: This does not work. Feel like when i press enter it refreshes the page